# Cannot assign to 'ResizeEnd' because it is a 'method group'

Tags: events, compiler-errors, method-group

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. In the designer for my form I added an event handler to the ResizeEnd event. The code generated looks like this:

this.ResizeEnd += new System.EventHandler(this.ResizeEndEventHandler);

This code, which was added to my source by Visual Studio, generates an error with the Description: Cannot Assign to 'ResizeEnd' because it is a 'method group'

I've seen this error before if you mistakenly try to assign a value to a method...but never when adding an event handler.

Any thoughts on what causes this or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That means that `ResizeEnd` is a method, not an event.

Comment: I realize that...as I said I've seen this before with methods...however I added the event handler in the designer in the events panel I created an event handler for the ResizeEnd event????